# Excel XLookup help: Looking to add left of column

Tags: excel, vlookup, xlookup

I am trying to do an xlookup or a vlookup (reverse) where I would like to input Under column L2 --> the # from Cell BF12 = 21. Essentially, I would like to add 2 columns left of the first NO (right to left) into the L2 and then thus onwards for L3 (3 columns etc)

[image]

Comment: What is problem you are facing to do so? Post your currently used formula and also show what result do you expect.

Comment: Sorry about that - My expected result in L2 (under BQ12) should "21",  L3 (BP12) should be 0 and so forth.

Comment: @user20102590 oh, seems i misunderstood "add 2 columns" above. You can use `=OFFSET(BA12,0,MATCH("NO",BA12:BH12,0)-2)` where the last -2 is for L2, -3 for L3 etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier using `MATCH` and `OFFSET`:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(BA12,0,MATCH("NO",BA12:BH12,0)-2,1,-2))
```

Above is for L2, for L3, change the width from -2 to -3 (and so on...)

```
=SUM(OFFSET(BA12,0,MATCH("NO",BA12:BH12,0)-2,1,-3))
```

Comment: for the above; this sums both columns in 

i.e for L2: it shows up as 46 and L3; shows up at 46 a well.

Comment: @user20102590 there are only 2 numbers on row 12, 21 and 25 which adds up to 46. since "jun 22" is blank L3 will add 0 + 21 + 25 = 46